# Find filenames with regexp group capture

Tags: ruby, regex, file, glob, regex-group

I'm way to find matching files by regexp and also supports groups in the regexp. Like:

```
match_files('/home/(*)/**/(*).txt')
```

would return something like:

```
[ ['/home/bob/docs/abc.txt', 'bob', 'abc'], ['/home/sue/archive/docs/def.txt', 'sue', 'def'] ]
```

Guard does something like this. I'm not looking to match this specific regex; rather to match any arbitrary regex input that might be provided.

Dir.glob() normally returns a flat array and doesn't support groups. I'm trying to locate a library or some technique that would support this kind of thing, for a DSL.

Comment: So what have you tried? We need to see your attempts.

Comment: I tried Dir.glob(), as the question implies, which yields empty results. I tried looking up any libraries or APIs which might do it, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Requests to locate libraries are off topic, but since this question also asks for "or some technique," I'll vote to leave it open.

Comment: mahemoff, I deleted my answer (a regex for the example given) because it didn't address your question.  You may have wondered why two of the three answers focused solely on your example.  I can't speak for @Blake, but when I saw the example my brain went into regex-mode.  Then when I saw Blake's answer, that became the question.  So it was Blake's fault. :-)

Comment: Understand @CarySwoveland. Sorry it was unclear. I mentioned it's for a DSL, but should have made it more obvious that was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to locate a library or trick that would support this kind of thing, for a DSL.

So your question seem to be off topic, because you are asking to recommend or find a tool or library to solve your problem.

Also, your question should include valid code examples:

```
['/home/bob/docs/abc.txt', 'bob', 'readme']
```

I guess it's supposed to mean

```
['/home/bob/docs/abc.txt', 'bob', 'abc']
```

Anyways... I think the question is quite interesting, but I don't think that you can't solve it with the standard library.

Dir.glob:

> Returns true if path matches against pattern. The pattern is not a
>   regular expression; instead it follows rules similar to shell filename
>   globbing. It may contain the following metacharacters...

The only reasonable thing to do is to allow special characters, parse the string, extract the matches, create a glob and then apply matching to the filenames.

Comment: "readme" was a typo, updated. The question is on-topic. The extract you quoted ask for a library or "trick", meaning I will settle for any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
regex = %r{/home/([^/]+)/.*/([^/]+).txt}
`find .`.split.grep(regex).map { |l| l.match(regex) }.map(&:to_a)
```

Could certainly be improved.